# How to extract and set value to Switch at same time ? React

Tags: reactjs

I've got Switch element in React app for the Update record function and i want the Switch element to show the current state and set the new state and save it, but once i set the current state with `checked` property can not change the state again, here's what i tried

```
    <Switch
       color="primary"
       name="Status"
       onBlur={handleBlur}
       onChange={handleStatus}
       value={editApp.Status}
       checked={!!editApp.Status}
    />


 const handleStatus = (event) => {
    console.log('statusState', statusState);
    // if (statusState === 1)
    setStatusState((prev) => !prev);
    console.log('statusState', statusState);
    // if (statusState === 0) setStatusState(1);
  };
```

And the `editApp` is a state,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // get user and set form fields
    GetApplicationsDataById(applicationId, applicationResultResponse2, applicationResultReject2);
  }, [isEdit]);

  const applicationResultResponse2 = (result) => {
    setEditApp(result);
    handleSnackBar('Success !', 'success');
    setStatusState(result.Status);
  };
```

Any idea how to it ? thanks.

Comment: just use `setStatusState(event.target.checked)` or `event.target.value` (idk which one is used)

Comment: thing is switch doesnt animate the change on the view

Comment: this might be because you have that `checked={!!editApp.Status}` 
you have that `setStatusState` which means there is a `[statusState, setStatusState] = useState() ` so for checked you need `checked={statusState}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setState

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  statusState: !prevState.check
}));
```

If you are using hook

```
const [statusState, setStatusState] = useState(false);
// ...
setStatusState(prevCheck => !prevCheck);
```

Update for hooks:

```
render() {
  const [statusState, setStatusState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Switch
       color="primary"
       name="Status"
       onBlur={handleBlur}
       onChange={() => setStatusState(prevCheck => !prevCheck)}
       value={statusState}
       checked={!!statusState}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: i already tried this, but Switch isnt working, state can not change after `checked={!!editApp.Status}`.

Comment: updated my answer, you need to use state value - statusState